# Magento 2 - Adding <style></style> tag in head

Tags: magento2, styles

How I can add critical path css rending in 
`<style>body{color:#202020}</style>` in header?

I did research but not getting clear picture. I can add **meta** and **custom css** file in **`default_head_blocks.xml`** **but not sure about adding style tags in header section.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make changes in any file to add style tag in head. You can do it from admin panel.

From admin **Menu** Go to **Content->Design->Configuration**. Now  select you store view and click on edit from Action column.

Now under **Other Settings** Tab select **HTML Head** section and you can add your style inside **Scripts and Style Sheets** input.

Comment: Perfect this option is similar to Magento 1 but I need to load it via phtml or layout file for CMS page only.

Comment: then instead of phtml file create separate css file and add that to your cms page

Comment: @Piyush do you have any reference for it

Answer (score 1):

You can add style tags directly into `header.phtml` which can be found under `app/design/frontend/Your_Vendor/Your_Theme/Magento_Theme/templates/html` if you have extended it in your theme or in the theme module of core magento (`app/code/Magento/Theme` or `vendor/Magento/Module_Theme`).

**Do not change core files , extend it on your own theme.**

Comment: I tried with phtml file in my theme and clear the cache but no help. Other scripts are loaded in head but not <style>..</style> tag.

Comment: Please be clear on what you are asking, you have mentioned header in question description and head in question itself. Both are different things.

Comment: It's works. Custom template was not loading. Thanks for the quick help. One more query is there any way to load scripts meta or style only for cms page and not for whole site?

Comment: You can add the script urls in cms_index_index.xml  and check if it works.

Comment: Also mark my answer as accepted if it helped you